# Makefile ifeq problem

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile  some thing like given below:

```
....
ifeq ($(strip $(MY_LIB)), $(strip $(SH_LIB))
    @echo "TRUE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
else 
    @echo "FALSE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
endif
......
```

With this I am getting into problem. That is It goes into else when both of them has same value. I confirmed with prints and it shows both are having the same string. 
In the root makefile,

```
SH_LIB := display
```

Even when MY_LIB is having display, It always goes to else part and prints
FALSE - display display.

After lots of changes, i was able to get it.

```
....
ifeq ("strip $(MY_LIB)", "display")
    @echo "TRUE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
else 
    @echo "FALSE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
endif
.....
```

After this change, it went inside the TRUE. 
Can somebody explain this?

**EDIT:**
I have put the similar code in root make file and it perfectly working.

Comment: So you cannot reproduce the error without having another makefile `include` this one. Try to reduce these files to the minimum that still shows the error, then post the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snip, try to remove the space inside the `ifeq` after the comma. You're also missing an ending right paren in the `ifeq`:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(MY_LIB)),$(strip $(SH_LIB)))
    @echo "TRUE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
else 
    @echo "FALSE-$(MY_LIB) $(SH_LIB)"
    ......
endif
```

Comment: regarding the parenthesis, it was a Copy/Paste mistake. So in the actual file its fine. (Otherwise, it gives error). Coming to your second point, even after removing the space after ",", i am facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried in root Makefile and its working. This is .mk file, which is being included from some other makefile.